# AVPlayer not playing MP3 audio file in documents directory iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, avfoundation, avplayer

I'm using AVPlayer to play a MP3 located in the documents directory (file is confirmed to be in there) - I load the `AVPlayerItem` wait for the `AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay` then instantiate the `AVPlayer` with the item and play.

The `AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay` does get called, but no audio actually plays, anyone have an idea why?

```
- (void)checkFileExists {
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[self.urlForEightBarAudioFile path]]) {
        [self beginEightBarDownload];
    } else {
        // set up audio
        [self setupAudio];

        //NSLog(@"file %@ already exists", [self.urlForEightBarAudioFile path]);
    }
}


- (void)setupAudio
{
    AVAsset *eightBarAsset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:self.urlForEightBarAudioFile];
    self.eightBarsPlayerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:eightBarAsset];
    [self.eightBarsPlayerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[AVPlayerItem class]])
    {
        AVPlayerItem *item = (AVPlayerItem *)object;

        if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"])
        {
            switch(item.status)
            {
                case AVPlayerItemStatusFailed:
                    break;
                case AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay:
                    self.player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:self.eightBarsPlayerItem];
                    [self.player play];
                    NSLog(@"player item status is ready to play");
                    break;
                case AVPlayerItemStatusUnknown:
                    NSLog(@"player item status is unknown");
                    break;
            }
        }
        else if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"playbackBufferEmpty"])
        {
            if (item.playbackBufferEmpty)
            {
                NSLog(@"player item playback buffer is empty");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this:

```
- (void)setupAudio
{
 if([NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[self.urlForEightBarAudioFile absoluteString]])
 {
   AVAsset *eightBarAsset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:self.urlForEightBarAudioFile];
   self.eightBarsPlayerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:eightBarAsset];
   self.eightBarsPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:self.eightBarsPlayerItem]; //forgot this line
   [self.eightBarsPlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil]; // add observer for player not item
 }
}
```

Refer [avplayer-and-local-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577471/avplayer-and-local-files) link

Comment: Thanks, but I already check for file existence, i've edited my post to show that.

Comment: Ahh right, so if you playing from local source then you have to observe the player, but if you're playing from remote source then you observe the player item? Am i right in thinking that? your answer worked perfectly, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in swift

```
func setupAudio() {
 if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(self.urlForEightBarAudioFile.absoluteString) {
   self.eightBarsPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: AVAsset(URL: self.urlForEightBarAudioFile))
   self.eightBarsPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: self.eightBarsPlayerItem)
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)setupAudio
{
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
  AVAsset *eightBarAsset = [AVAsset   assetWithURL:self.urlForEightBarAudioFile];
  self.eightBarsPlayerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:eightBarAsset];
  self.eightBarsPlayer = [AVPlayer  playerWithPlayerItem:self.eightBarsPlayerItem]; //forgot this line
  [self.eightBarsPlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil]; // add observer for player not item
});
```

}