# Getting mp3's from documents folder

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7

This question is about Objective-C, Xcode and iOS. I want to access the mp3 or m4a files inside the applications documents folder and get these files `MPMediaItemPropertyTitle`,`MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle` and `MPMediaItemPropertyArtist` informations. After that I want to play these files. Actually I want to make a music player application and I need help. Thanks in advance...

Comment: What's the **applications documents folder**? There's an applications folder, a bundle for your application, and a documents folder for each user. You need to clarify..

Comment: I meant Documents folder @cacau

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use below code to get array of mp3file and play it with AVAudio player

```
-(void)getallMp3Files
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSArray *filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory  error:nil];
    NSMutableArray *arrMp3Files=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (NSString *str in filePathsArray) {
        NSString *strFileName=[str.lastPathComponent lowercaseString];
        if([strFileName.pathExtension isEqualToString:@"mp3"])
        {
        NSLog(@"%@",str);
            [arrMp3Files addObject:str];
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this below links, Hope it will be helpful

[AVPlayer not playing MP3 audio file in documents directory iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155055/avplayer-not-playing-mp3-audio-file-in-documents-directory-ios)

[AVPlayer And Local Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577471/avplayer-and-local-files)