# How to play mp3 in iOS with Obj-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mp3, media-player

I've a question in Objective-C, I'm working on an iOS application that should play a specific mp3 set of files -242 mp3 files exactly-, So could someone tell me what is the best way to play them all, I mean should I put them in a server, making them all local or what ? and how should I code them in Xcode.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577471/avplayer-and-local-files,Thsi post explain how to play mp3 file form local and from url

Comment: Thank you all guys.

Answer (score 1):

Apple provides `AVAudioPlayer` for handling audio media files. Another library you could use that works with Core Audio under the hood is [EZAudio](https://github.com/syedhali/EZAudio)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
NSUrl *videoUrl = [NSUrl urlWithString:@"url"];
MPMoviePlayerViewController *playerViewController = 
    [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString: videoUrl]];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:playerViewController];
```