# how we can play multiple remote URL from API having different format for each using AVplayer in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

how we can play multiple remote URL from API having different format for each using AVplayer in objective c

using :[AVPlayer And Local Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577471/avplayer-and-local-files)

tried this way also :
[Get parts of a NSURL in objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692947/get-parts-of-a-nsurl-in-objective-c)

Comment: Different format mean mp4 etc ?

Comment: like different url format example like , its working for http://217.146.71.24/myhits.mp3  this but not working for http://icecast.err.ee/raadiotallinn.mp3  , these typer of urls

Comment: is it giving any error? some time if file size is bigger it takes few seconds to start .

Comment: share code where you are adding url in queue or direct.

Comment: yeah ! initWithSessionInfo: XPC connection interrupted

Comment: i am getting urls from api then same demo is using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577471/avplayer-and-local-files

Comment: yeah! i got solution . AppTransport security and exception domain that was not added in info.plist . its working now!

Comment: ok , Best of luck.